# PPA containing newer version of screen

Tags: 14.04, ppa, gnu-screen

The GNU screen version for Ubuntu 14.04 seems to be 4.01, which was last updated **May 2006**! The newest screen version was updated **May 2014**

I know I can compile my own version, but I'm dealing with ~60 servers and it's a bit of a PITA. Is there a PPA or a *.deb file being maintained somewhere?

Comment: You make it sound like Ubuntu's screen packaging is incredibly out of date. screen upstream was dormant for many years. The current series only came out in April, after 14.04 was released.

Comment: Ah, this clarifies quite a bit. From my perspective, it *is* incredibly out of date, but this is not the fault of ubuntu from your description

Comment: It is by definition only around six months out of date :)

Comment: Ha ha sure - I was just shocked at that year number, but it all makes more sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[screen 4.2.1 is available from trusty-backports](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-backports/screen). See the [user backports documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) for information on enabling and using packages from the backports repository.